# Importing Schema Issues

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, hana, azure-data-factory

I have my source table in SAP HANA with almost 80 columns, the destination tables on azure DW/Mapping document has 60 columns. (They are mapped to source columns with different names). Now When I am trying to create a source dataset I gave the linked service which was created by my TL and Once I Select that HANA linked to service, It is not showing me any table option under linked service to select and import schemas. Why is that? It is throwing gateway timeout error. 
PS: The Linked service was created by my manager and I don't know any credentials for that

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** as you haven't given any adequate evidence. As a result, urgent action is required to improve this post!

Comment: Correction in grammar and formatted.

Answer (score 0):

SAP Hana only supports query, not table name.

1. Create a pipeline first and drag a copy activity into the pipeline. Reference your dataset in your copy activity.
2. Then you will see a browser table button. You could construct your query there.
   [image]
3. When you want to edit your json, please use the button instead of the button in the activity node.
   [image]

Comment: I did that Fang, the issue is in source data set where we select the linked service for source and the source table and import schemas from source. I am unable to see the table name option. I have given the query in copy pipeline activity.

Comment: I was getting the gateway error and cleared it but, it is throwing an error 2200 saying column mapping is an error. I mapped 49 columns out of 60 columns is it the result of that I am getting this error? The other columns doesn't have any mapping information.

Comment: Trying to write the JSON code for column mappings in the created pipeline, but once I write the code and click on finish the main copy activity is being deleted.

Comment: Hi Sam, I updated my answer. Please share the screenshot when you hit the error. In the meantime, you could also create a support ticket if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the issues were source has column concatenation and destination table didn't have a correct logic in concatenation and few columns which were not present in source, I did the explicit mapping. And made it one-one relation from source to destination in Azure. It works now. Thank you all!